# How to prevent misalignment of a vertical column when a node label is displayed

Tags: nodes, labels

I am trying to make a vertical column of various moon phases using a macro that generates circles, but when I add a node label to a circle (to designate that it is a full moon) it shifts the circle that contains the label slightly up and to the right.

```
\documentclass[leqno,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar,fpu}

\newcommand{\moon}[2][]{%
\def\lunarage{#2}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\textF{ifthenelse(\lunarage==15,"F","")}
\tikz []{
    \draw (0,0) circle [radius=1ex];
    \node[color=black] (0,0) {\textF};
    %
    }%
}
\begin{document}\noindent%
    \foreach \d in {0,1,...,30}{%
    \moon[]{\d}  \\   }
\end{document}
```

THANKS for any help!

Comment: isn't this an exact duplicate of the question you just asked? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297793/how-to-prevent-an-object-from-moving-when-adding-a-node-label

Comment: yes it is.  The first one didn't display the code correctly.

Comment: please do not do do that, you can _edit_ an existing question (or delete the old one)

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions.  This is my first question so I had some trouble with the editing procedure.  Thanks for all of the help.

Answer (score 1):

You're drawing a `circle` and a `node` over it. As this node is wider than the circle, this particular `moon` is wider than all other `moons`.

I think it's better to use a `circular` node than a `circle` with a not-drawn node over it. You must be sure that `minimum size` is big enough to encompass `F` (or whatever letter you want). This way, all `moons` have same size.

```
\documentclass[leqno,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar,fpu}

\newcommand{\moon}[2][]{%
\def\lunarage{#2}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\textF{ifthenelse(\lunarage==15,"F","")}
\tikz []{
    \node[draw, circle, color=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=5mm] (0,0) {\textF};
    %
    }%
}
\begin{document}\noindent%
    \foreach \d in {0,1,...,30}{%
    \moon[]{\d}  \\   }
\end{document}
```

[image]